# How do I make the compiler choose the BinaryWriter.Write overload I want?

Tags: delphi, binarywriter

I am using binary readers and writers to read / write data to a file. For example for this:

```
MyWriter.Write(Ord(TMyEnum(2)));
```

I would expect it to write down SmallInt to be read with

```
MyReader.ReadSmallInt
```

But in IDE I see it writes down byte. How do I force the writer to write the type that I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast it to `Smallint`

```
Smallint(SomeEnum)
```

Comment: Will this ensure the proper overloaded method is called?